# processing of list of list

Tags: python, list

I am working on lists of list

input:

```
x = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c'],['d','d','d']]
```

and am looking for an output:

```
s = ['a_b_c_d','a_b_c_d','a_b_c_d']
```

Kindly let me know how can I do this using list comprehension.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I assume the fourth `'a_b_c_d'` is a typo?

Comment: `['_'.join(l[0] for l in x)] * len(x)` But, why?

Comment: @Marcin Submit that as a solution, we are still not sure exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @Marcin: Why `l[0]` and not, say, `l[-1]`? ;-)

Comment: @aix Fewer characters ;)

Comment: I removed the fourth `'a_b_c_d'` since the OP accepted an answer which had 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> x = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c'],['d','d','d']]
>>> map('_'.join, zip(*x))
['a_b_c_d', 'a_b_c_d', 'a_b_c_d']
```

… although @aix's list comprehension is more list-comprehensible.

Comment: I think this is a very good use case for `map`. It should also be faster than the list comprehension because the method call is pushed to the C side. One thing to note though is that this returns an iterable instead of a list in Python 3.

Answer (score 11):

```
In [6]: x = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c'],['d','d','d']]

In [7]: ['_'.join(s) for s in zip(*x)]
Out[7]: ['a_b_c_d', 'a_b_c_d', 'a_b_c_d']
```

As requested, this uses a list comprehension. See @eumiro's answer for a `map()`-based solution that I think is just as good.

Comment: It does not produce the result the OP wants though... your result contains 3 elements instead of 4.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think that's a typo. See my comment to the question.